# SharePoint Parallel Tasks

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

Using SharePoint 2013 Designer but workflow 2010,
I have a Parallel Section in my workflow that has 3 collects.
Using if statements, it can either start 2 or 3.

But whenever the workflow starts, 1 task is immediately "In Progress" but the
other two take long to get started.

The first task is ready right away. The Second takes around 5 minutes to become "In Progress" and the third takes up to 20 mins to become "In Progress"

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps 'Pause' in Workflow step? in SharePoint, a pause of 2 minutes for one.

If the not 'Pause', at queue of workflow processes, at first stop\start SharePoint Timer PowerShell or Command promt (Administrator):

SharePoint 2010, 2013: **net stop SPTimerV4 / net start SPTimerV4**

SharePoint 2007: **net stop SPTimerV3 / net start SPTimerV3**

SharePoint 2003: **net stop SPTimer / net start SPTimer**

then again testing Workflow.